# add html text to label in titanium

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, appcelerator

I have an html text that has some html tags.

My Question :

How can I add that text into a label without those tags but keeping the text alignment?

For example :

if I have an "< /br>" as tag I need the same effect in the text added to the label but without the "< /br>" appearing in the text.

How can I make that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple solutions, if it is only about spacing (`<br>`) you could actually just replace the `<br>` with `\n` with regular expressions for example.

If it is more complicated (bold, italic, underlined, links) you can use [Attributed Strings](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.AttributedString). If it is much more complicated than the supported types in Attributed strings you can use a webview, or [StyledLabel](https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.styledlabel).

Comment: how can i replace the "/"? I'm trying this mister.replace(/<br />/g, '/n'). but it does note work

Comment: you need to use `\n` not `/n` ;)

Comment: Also, replace only does 1 instance, you need to replace all ;)

Comment: The \N solved the enter problems but it keeps the / character. I'm doing it like this:  var str = String(mStr).replace(/&/g, '').replace(/</g, '').replace(/>/g, '').replace(/"/g, '').replace(/br/g, '\n');

Comment: that is a terrible solution. Just go with replacing `<br>` and <br />`. Don't go look for other elements like you do. And don't chain replaces: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

In Android you can apply

```
   Html.fromHtml("Html text")
```

i hope this could be help you.

Comment: it is about appcelerator, not native Android